# How Does Upsert Work When No External Id Is Specified?

Tags: apex, externalid, upsert

I have looked at the documentation on [Database Methods](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=apex%20upsert%20without%20external%20id). What I do not understand is, what happens when an `upsert` is performed without specifying an external id field? Is it just based on whether or not the record has an `Id`?

Answer (score 1):

It just simply check if ID field is set then SFDC update the record orther wise it just insert record.

for ex:

```
List<Account> al = new list<Account>();

Account a1 = new account(ID='0019000001dK6Rd', Name='XXXX Test Account 1'); 
al.add(a1); // This is updated as ID is passed 

Account a2 = new account(MyExtID__c='Target#001', Name='XXXX Test Account 2'); 
al.add(a2);// This is updated as External ID is passed

Account a3 = new account( Name='XXXX Test Account 3'); 
al.add(a3);// This is inserted as both ID & External ID is NOT passed

Database.upsert(al);
```

Update:

> Usage:
>   Upsert is a merging of the words insert and update. This call is
>   available for objects if the object has an external ID field or a
>   field with the idLookup field property.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this statement up? It was my assumption from the start, but I couldn't find any supporting materials.

Comment: This is not an assumption. You can run the code and verify it with appropriate data. Also added link of documentation.

Comment: It is not the correctness of your answer that I am unsure of, but its completeness. Does the system only consider the Id field if no external field is specified?

Comment: Yes, There are only 2 ways record can be uniquely identify. one is ID and second is unique external id.